# Pass Spring model attribute to JS script

Tags: javascript, spring, model, thymeleaf

So, I'm having my data parsed to json and then put in the model attributes. Like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/{id}")
public String getNetworkDetails(Model model, @PathVariable String id) throws JsonProcessingException{

    model.addAttribute("poolHashrates", findAndDisplayDataService.getAllPools(Long.valueOf(id)));
    model.addAttribute("poolDataJson", findAndDisplayDataService.returnPoolsAsJson(Long.valueOf(id)));

    return "networkDetails :: modalContents";
}
```

Next I'm trying to assign a `poolDataJson` string to a JS variable in html fragment through:

```
<script>
    var data = eval('('+'${poolDataJson}'+')');
    console.log(data);
</script>
```

What I would like to do with the data, is pass it to external JavaScript file as a data for my pie-chart. But first I'm getting an error on a string assignment:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I have also tried assigning json string to hidden input via:

```
<input type="hidden" id="networkId" th:value="${poolDataJson}"/></td>
```

And then read it with:

```
var data = document.getElementById('networkId').innerHTML;
console.log(data);
```

But again, nothing prints in console. When I put the `${poolDataJson}` in

it prints properly on a page...

Comment: Try assigning poolDataJson to variable like var data = ${poolDataJson}; an then pass data into eval.

Comment: Same. Unexpected token on `var json = ${poolDataJson};`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be returning a String as JSON text.  Instead,  you should return regular Java objects and then evaluate it like this (thymeleaf will automatically convert objects to JSON):

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
var data = /*[[${poolDataJson}]]*/ {};
console.log(data);
</script>
```

As for your errors. I would have to guess that your method `findAndDisplayDataService.returnPoolsAsJson` is returning invalid JSON.  Without a real example, it's hard to tell.